# Combinatorics algorithm in Python: how to get a count per each unique combo that is present in another list of combos

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, loops, combinations

This is hard to explain, So let me get straight into explaining the data and code.

I have a data frame with each row containing all possible combinations of the characters A, B and C. Order of the elements is not taken into consideration.

```
| vars_set |
| ---------|
| {b, c, a} |
| {b, c}      |
| {c, a}      |
| {a}      |
| {b}      |
| {c}      |
```

I also have a list of sets with the same character combination but there can be duplicates here and not all possible combination will be in this list.

```
actual_combos=[{'a', 'b', 'c'},{'a'},{'a'},{'b'},{'b', 'c'},{'a', 'c'},{'a', 'c'}]
```

What I would like to do is take each row from the data frame and check how many of the above sets in actual_combos have all elements present within that specific combination of the dataframe row value.

So using the example data, the output would look like this.

```
| vars_set | combo_count |
| ---------| ------------|
| {b, c, a}|7|
| {b, c}   |2|
| {c, a}   |4|
| {b, a}   |3|
| {a}      |2|
| {b}      |1|
| {c}      |0|
```

All sets from the list in actual combos are present in (b, c, a) so the count is 7.

The count for (c) is 0 since none of the sets in actual_combos have the value C only.
I think you get the point...

Now, my real data set is much larger and has 17 unique elements and not just 3 like in the example. I actually have a working piece of code, but the issue is it's quite slow.

So I'm looking for some help with optimizing my code, so it can run faster. Here is my full code.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from itertools import combinations
    
    input = ['a','b','c']
    output = sum([list(map(list, combinations(input, i))) for i in range(len(input) + 1)], [])
    df_all_combs = pd.DataFrame(output)
    df_all_combs['vars_ls']=df_all_combs.values.tolist()
    df_all_combs['vars_ls'] = [[x for x in inner_list if x is not None] for inner_list in df_all_combs['vars_ls']]
    df_all_combs['combo_count']=""
    df_all_combs['vars_set'] = df_all_combs['vars_ls'].apply(set)
    
    actual_combos=[{'a', 'b', 'c'},{'a'},{'a'},{'b'},{'b', 'c'},{'a', 'c'},{'a', 'c'}]
    
    for i in range(df_all_combs.shape[0]):
        count=0
        for item in actual_combos:  
            if len(item-df_all_combs['vars_set'].iloc[i]) == 0:
                   count=count+1
            df_all_combs['combo_count'].iloc[i] = count
            
    df_all_combs
```

Comment: Please consider upvoting and/or accepting answers if they were helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I only slightly changed your data creation part, as I assume that it's not the main interest here. Just two little remarks: Please don't overwrite `input`, it's a Python built-in. And you don't have to initialize columns like this `df_all_combs['combo_count']=""`, create them when you need them.

I think the interesting part is where you compare the sets to each other. Generally, you should avoid looping over the rows of a dataframe, it's slow. I got rid of the for loop by writing a small function (`get_combo_count`) and applying it to the column `'vars_set'` (using the `pandas.Series.map` method).

When you look inside the function, you can see that I also got rid of the second for loop and instead apply my own little `lambda` function using Python's `map` function. The output of this function is a list-like containing booleans, which can be passed to the `sum` function, thus avoiding the need of a `count` variable.

On my machine, the revised code runs about 4-5 times faster than the original code.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
    
my_input = ['a','b','c']
output = sum([list(map(list, combinations(my_input , i))) for i in range(len(my_input ) + 1)], [])
df_all_combs = pd.DataFrame(output)
df_all_combs['vars_ls']=df_all_combs.values.tolist()
df_all_combs['vars_ls'] = [[x for x in inner_list if x is not None] for inner_list in df_all_combs['vars_ls']]
df_all_combs['vars_set'] = df_all_combs['vars_ls'].apply(set)
    
actual_combos=[{'a', 'b', 'c'},{'a'},{'a'},{'b'},{'b', 'c'},{'a', 'c'},{'a', 'c'}]
    

def get_combo_count(row):
    return sum(map(lambda x: x.issubset(row), actual_combos))
        
df_all_combs['combo_count'] = df_all_combs['vars_set'].map(get_combo_count)
df_all_combs
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [powerset recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from `itertools` and [`set.issubset()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset):

```
counts = {}
for input_psi in powerset(inputs):
    counts[input_psi] = sum(item.issubset(input_psi) for item in actual_combos)
```

This seems ~300x faster (tested up to 20 characters), but this may vary based on actual input.

```
import pandas as pd

# Helpers
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    # From: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
    from itertools import chain, combinations
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))


# Inputs
inputs = ['a','b','c']
actual_combos = [{'a', 'b', 'c'},{'a'},{'a'},{'b'},{'b', 'c'},{'a', 'c'},{'a', 'c'}]

# Build Dataframe
counts = {}
for input_psi in powerset(inputs):
    counts[input_psi] = sum(item.issubset(input_psi) for item in actual_combos)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [(set(k), v) for (k,v) in counts.items()],
    columns=['vars_set', 'combo_count']
)

print(df)
```